# UML software with C# code generation feature

Tags: windows, c#, uml

I need a program to design UML class diagrams and generate C# code from it.
My goal is to build an UML class diagram for some personal project and generate the backbone of my code with it.

For instance, the software would allow me to build a class diagram like this:
[image: class diagram]

And generate the following code from it:

```
public class Component 
{
    public void operation()
    {
    }
}

public class ConcreteComponent : Component
{
    public void operation()
    {
    }
}

public class Decorator : Component
{
    private object component;
    public void operation()
    {
    }
}

public class ConcreteDecorator : Decorator
{
    public void operation()
    {
    }
}
```

An additional much appreciated feature would be the possibility to generate the code with `System.Collections` attributes to implement UML composition or aggregation.

The software I'm looking for needs to run on Windows 7 and 8(.1) 32-bit and 64-bit and I don't mind the price.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: I added some details hoping this will help.

Comment: Of course I did. I added an example of code based on UML class diagram.

Comment: If you're going to add more detail to the question, add things like do you need a WYSIWYG type tool, support for sequence diagrams, diagram generation from code, etc. You don't need to explain UML and code generation because those are well defined terms in software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual studio 201X is your best choice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409445.aspx

The VS Diagram desginer is a UML tool that I've used for years.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is a freeware UML modeling tool that may work for you. It's primarily focused on Java development but it does have the option to generate code in C#.

[image: ArgoUML code generation]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know if this project is still active? On their site I see that the last version is from december 2011.

Comment: It may not be. I've used off and on since 2005 and I've not had any problems with it.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I have used ArgoUML and really liked it; lots of features and pretty solid program. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be active anymore, but it is still worth checking out for all the good features.

Answer (score 3):

WhiteStarUML

It's in active development, has been around for a few years now, it's Open Source and the current maintainer does listens.
Plus, it's easy to use, and it has the undo/redo feature that ArgoUML is missing.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/

Comment: Interesting project, good rating on sourceforge.

Answer (score 2):

Modelio is basically a free & open source UML modeling tool which is active and UML2 compliant.

The free edition of Modelio does not provide C# code generation support however the commercial version of Modelio supports it. The commercial version is distributed by Modeliosoft. You can use it with the C# Designer module which provides C# code generation feature.

- [Modelio by Modeliosoft](http://www.modeliosoft.com/fr/modelio-store/solutions/modelio-modeliosoft-distribution.html)
- [C# Designer module](http://www.modeliosoft.com/fr/modelio-store/modules/generators/cs-designer.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) does a good job of this too...

They have a [free booklet](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/downloads/resources/booklets/uml_code_engineering.pdf) with in-depth information on how code generation and reverse engineering works with Enterprise Architect.

There are also [third party plugins](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/3rdparty.html#CodeTrigger).

It's been around a long time and is well supported. There is also a lot more [information out there](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise-architect/code-engineering/code-engineering.html).

Comment: Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Given the not great question a bunch to work off a bunch of those aren't really relevant but it could still be improveed with like why are you recommending it etc.

Comment: Better Nick?  A simple google query... 

https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sparx+systems+enterprise+architect+code+generation

Would give you the same information.  I didn't state it because it's not hard to find once you know the name of the product.